# How to position one React component inside another (grid) component

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, widget, position

I'm making a News website and I have a component that maps over articles (that i fetched from an API) and displays them in a grid. I also have a separate component that displays Latest News.
I need to position the Latest News widget "inside" the article grid, in a way where the Latest news widget will make up the 3rd and 6th element of the grid. Here's an example:
[image: Example]

How do i do this?

Comment: What you have tried  so far ?

Comment: So far the menu, the article grid and the widget are 3 separate components and i applied display: flex to position them next to each other. Can't figure out how to get the widget to "intercept" the grid

Comment: can you show any visuals of what you are trying to achieve there is no code and visual as well?

Comment: The photo i posted is what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return can look like this. Remove the first four elements and map the rest. I have considered MUI grid component here but the logic will be same everywhere.

```
return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item lg={8}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item lg={6}>
              {news[0]}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item lg={6}>
              {news[1]}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item lg={6}>
              {news[2]}
            </Grid>
            <Grid item lg={6}>
              {news[3]}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item lg={4}>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item> Latest News</Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        {news.slice(4).map((new) => {
          return <Grid item lg={4}>{new}</Grid>;
        })}
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
```